# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Problem with wifi connections

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

After reinstalation my ubuntu i have problem with wireless conection. I dont see available wifi conection on ubunut gui any and networks. Internet working only via wired connection.
Problem is probably with a driver.

**ifconfig** print :

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:47:47:cb:cf:50  
          inet addr:10.11.4.83  Bcast:10.11.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b535:2133:7777:aece/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8419 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9415235 (9.4 MB)  TX bytes:1242271 (1.2 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:162028 (162.0 KB)  TX bytes:162028 (162.0 KB)
```

**iwconfig** print :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2** print :

```
3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
0e:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8520] (rev 01)
```

but my workmate with this same model of laptop have this relust

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
      Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

It can be problem maybe with this driver **iwlwifi**. Somebody know how to install this driver or fix this problem, i dont find any solution in internet.

EDIT
Here is result of script 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25326132/

**rfkill list** nothing output

EDIT

Kernel update, resolve my problem, thanks a lot of Pilot6

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Something is wrong with you kernel, maybe it is partially installed. There is no `iwlwifi` at all now. Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and post the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: You can run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to install `4.4.0-92` kernel.

Comment: Output with another kernel 
https://ibb.co/mZX4zv

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with a partially installed kernel, probably without the `extra` package. Modile `iwlwifi` is not loading.

Update the system by `sudo apt full-upgrade`, it will install a new kernel.